# How to use array values from string_to_array to JOIN to a look-up table

Tags: postgresql

I have an `animals` table like this:

```
      Column      |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 animal_code      | character varying(3)     |           | not null | 
 animal_type_code | character(2)             |           | not null | 
 description      | character varying(64)    |           | not null |
```

Typical content might be:

```
 animal_code | animal_type_code |      description
-------------+------------------+------------------------------
 XAA         | T                | Not an animal, but a toaster
 1           | D                | This is a dog called Bob
 2           | C                | This cat is called Frank
 3           | C                | Wilf the cat has three legs
 4           | D                | Thunder is a dog
```

An existing stored procedure I'm working with receives a text string containing a comma-separated list of these `animal_code` values, like this:

```sql
store_pet_show_details(
  'London',                      -- p_venue      VARCHAR(64)
  '2019-12-03',                  -- p_date       TIMESTAMPTZ
  'XAA,91,22,23,74,15,64,47,12'  -- p_entrants   TEXT
);
```

I'm using `unnest(string_to_array(code_csv, ','))` to extract the animal entry codes.

It's probably very simple, but I just want to see if any entrants have an `animal_type_code` of "`T`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `trim`.

```sql
select animal_code, animal_type_code, description
 from animals
 inner join (select trim(e) entrant from unnest(string_to_array(p_entrants, ',')) e) t
 on animal_code = entrant
 where animal_type_code = 'T';
```